# iOS Google Maps V3 and usage limits

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3

Just converting to Google Maps V3 API and all is looking good.  The only question is usage limits.  This app is used by many and in the V2 API we had

```
key = <Google V2 Business API Key>
```

With V3 and JSON, there is no such key and have been reviewing the doc at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Where it says....

```
The Google Geocoding API has the following limits in place:
2,500 requests per 24 hour period.

Google Maps API for Business customers have higher limits:
100,000 requests per 24 hour period.
```

The question is how is this tracked?

1) Per iOS application no matter where it is / how many it is installed and running?

2) Per iOS device with the App?

The exact type of URL that we are using...

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@&output=json&sensor=false"
```

Anyway, if anyone knows how this is tracked and if it is indeed 1), then I guess no need for the Business key?

Answer (score 0):

As the Google Maps API is primarily designed for website the tracking is based on a IP/device base. Every Google API I know which uses a customer based tracking must include a API key for the tracking.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, not interested in tracking, just interested in the "over use" of the current V3 API using from iOS.

Comment: Where did you read about IP/device based tracking and not API key? As far as I know, Google only says about limits but not how they track these limits.